# AzureML: Autoscale ML Endpoint

Tags: azure-machine-learning-service

I have my model hosted on ACI compute. I'm trying to investigate what it would take to support auto-scaling of the underlying instances? If auto scaling isnt possible, then is there documentation to manually scale the endpoint?

Basically, I need to support high availability on this model endpoint.

A thought that I had was to manually publish the model to 2 endpoints and then add a Load Balander in front. Seems a little hacky...

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

We usually recommend deploying to AKS for high availability. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-deploy-azure-kubernetes-service